# How to efficiently migrate a 800GB database into a new one?

Tags: sql-server

We have an old database that is about 800GB with 5 tables each having a binary column storing files. We now have a new database with fewer tables and changed column names and in some cases also new datatypes. As an example, in the old db there is a version column that is a decimal. However it has only ever been used as an integer, so all the values are "1.00000", "2.00000" and so forth. In the new db, this field is just an int instead to make things line up correctly.

However, we now have a new requirement to migrate this old data to the new tables. I can quite easily do this using code such as C# but it is not very efficient. Inserting 100 000 rows to the new db took about 33 minutes on my machine. However, it would probably be faster do run this program on the actual DB server to avoid network transmissions. (The total number of rows is about 2 million) We have also tried using tools available in SSMS but the export wizard there does not allow for much of a "custom mapping" between columns. In both the old and the new db we have category fields but they are not the same so we need to map some of the old ones to the new ones. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this in SSMS.

Are there any recommended tools or approaches to solving this problem? I'm leaning towards perhaps replacing the values in the old db, such as categories, with the correct ones first and then I can do a migration using the export tools.

Comment: First thing I could recommend is try to add rows in bulk (several thousands or tens of thousands at a time). The inserts will be much more efficient. If you use entity framework, check latest EF and other libraries, as usually EF will insert one by one, which is slow. Another "easy" thing to do is to deactivate indexes and constraints like foreign keys during migration, and enable them again after that. Of course you may want to double check the correct status of your data after migration, since you don't have the umbrella of the DB anymore.

Comment: You might want to try migrating the DB via SSIS - it's quite performant. However, I am not sure, if it supports binary datatype.
However, doing this per bulk insert as Pac0 mentioned is a good approach. I would recommend executing this in a SQL Agent Job as SQL step. This way the action is performed on the DB alone and not on your local machine. Anyways, you might want to think about splitting this task up - otherwise you won't have a possibility to restart if any error occured.